# Unbind gnu-screen commands

Tags: gnu-screen

In copy mode, I don't want C-f to be bound to "page-down". What can I include in my .screenrc to unbind keys?

I tried
`bind f`
and 
`bind ^f`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
bind [-c class] key [command [args]]
```